# htaccess problem

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, wampserver

I am not able to get URL redirection to work.  It appears to be a problem with my `.htaccess` file.  I am using [WampServer](http://www.wampserver.com/en/).

Following is the code in .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^contactus index.php?file=c-contactus
```

Comment: This probably should belong to Server Fault.

Comment: try use logging to debug

Answer (score 3):

```
RewriteRule ^/?contactus(/)?$ index.php?file=c-contactus
```

Answer (score 2):

put a / before index.php?file=c-contactus

so it becomes:

```
/index.php?file=c-contactus
```

or

```
RewriteRule ^contactus$ index.php?file=c-contactus
```

Comment: edited, does your request end with a slash? If so, it will not work.

Comment: Remove the $ from the RewriteRule Above, or use mrinject's optional /

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
RewriteRule ^/contactus(.*) /index.php?file=c-contactus
```

Answer (score 0):

You must enable RewriteRule at first step.

[Look at here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869092/how-to-enable-mod-rewrite-for-apache-2-2)

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

Change the AllowOverride None to AllowOverride All

in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-deafult

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have mod_rewrite module enabled in your Apache server configuration first. One of the easiest way is to run a phpinfo() and look in Loaded Modules section as below: 
[image]

If you did't find the mod_rewrite there, edit the httpd.conf file in /wampserver/bin/apache/conf path and uncomment the following line:
`LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so`

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /your-project-folder/
RewriteRule ^contactus/?$ index.php?file=c-contactus [L,QSA]
```

If you working with localhost then please provide root folder name(In which your project avaiable) for url rewritebase

For example: If your index.php file under the **firstproject** folder then set like this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /firstproject/
RewriteRule ^contactus/?$ index.php?file=c-contactus [L,QSA]
```